# how to add touch event to jquery that work on ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad

I have this link: [Drag and Drop Examples](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.2/demos/external-dragging.html)

But it's drag feature doesn't work on iPad.

Please kindly suggest me how to make this work on iPad. I tried jQtouch, but it's not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This uses jQuery UI, which doesn't bind touch events by default.

I highly recommend "jQuery Touch Punch", which maps all jQuery UI events to their touch counterparts:

https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch

Comment: How to delete item after Being  Drop on Calender ?? help me :(

Comment: Since you didn't upvote or accept my answer, clearly my answer wasn't helpful. I'll let someone else try.

Comment: i did , i know its by event it but i cant create it  hmmm

Comment: The Touch Punch website has been updated with more info http://touchpunch.furf.com, including how to get help.